# How can I create a dependent drop down menu in the html interface

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a dependent drop down menu which is the data taken from the google spreadsheet

I am a entirely newbie for Google App-script. I wanna create a dependent drop down menu in html interface. But the drop down data must be taken from the google spreadsheet.

Is there any possible to create something like this type of list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build an interface to suite your requirement. Here's something that could help you get started -

Your `Code.gs` part if supposed to "get" the data from sheets and "return" the values when invoked -

```
var ID = 'Enter-Your-SpreadSheetID-Here';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle('Index');
}

function getOptions() {
  var rangeValues = activeSheet.getRange(2,1,activeSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  return rangeValues;
}
```

While you can access the entire `Index.html` from my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/schoraria911/google-apps-script/blob/master/Materialize%20CSS/Autocomplete/Index.html), the part of script that would help you get those values from sheet is as below -

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var optionsdropdown = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(value) {
            var optionsjson = value;
            $.each(optionsjson, function(index, data) {
                $('#optionsSelect').append($('<option/>', {
                    value: data,
                    text: data
                }));
            });
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.formselect.init(elems);
        }).getOptions();
    });
</script>
```

You can also read the entire post that I've created on this [here](https://script.gs/autocomplete-drop-down-options-from-spreadsheet-data/). Hope this helps!